Книги и учебные ресурсы по Dart и Flutter
Здесь мы попробуем собрать лучшие ответы и рекомендации насчёт литературы и других учебных ресурсов по языку Dart, фреймворку Flutter и популярным библиотекам.
Формат:
Название, Авторы. Год ISBN.

Формат для переведенной литературы:
Название, Авторы. Издательство, Год, ISBN.

Электронные ресурсы оформляются в виде ссылок.

Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте существующий.
Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.
Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям.
Сохраняйте алфавитную (лексикографическую) сортировку по названию книги. (когда она будет)

Не забывайте, что никакая теория не заменит опыта программирования! Читайте, пробуйте, тренируйтесь. Спрашивайте, если непонятно. Попробуйте запрограммировать свой проект, это лучший путь.

Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию.


Хорошие уроки по Flutter & Dart - https://www.youtube.com/@frezycode

@ЕвгенийЛи ответ ниже является общим, его может редактировать каждый

Спасибо, добавил)

Основные книги и ресурсы по Dart:
Учебные онлайн-ресурсы:

Официальная сайт Dart: https://dart.dev/ - лучший ресурс для изучения Dart.
Dart API Docs: https://api.dart.dev/ - всегда самая актуальная документация по Dart.
DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/ - онлайн-редактор, позволяющий писать и запускать код Dart непосредственно в браузере.  Отличный инструмент для экспериментирования и обучения.
Dart Academy: https://dart.academy/ - Сайт с учебными пособиями и статьями по Dart для разработчиков любого уровня.

Другие полезные ресурсы:

Pub.dev: https://pub.dev/ - официальный репозиторий пакетов Dart.  Здесь вы найдете множество готовых решений для различных задач.
Dart community on Medium: https://medium.com/dartlang -  блог с новостями, статьями и советами от разработчиков Dart.
r/dartlang (subreddit): https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/ -  сообщество Reddit, где можно задавать вопросы, делиться опытом и обсуждать Dart.

Книги:

Beginning Flutter with Dart: A practical guide to cross-platform mobile development, Rap Payne.  Apress, 2021. ISBN 978-1-4842-6227-5. Эта книга хороша для начинающих, совмещая изучение Dart с разработкой под Flutter.

Dart in Action, Chris Buckett. Manning Publications, 2015. ISBN 9781617292196. Эта книга, несмотря на возраст, всё ещё актуальна для понимания основных концепций Dart, хотя некоторые примеры могут требовать адаптации под новые версии языка.  Она больше подходит для изучения самого Dart, вне контекста Flutter.

Programming Dart: Creating robust, reusable, high-performance web applications, Devon Carew. O'Reilly Media, 2013. ISBN 978-1-4493-4208-1. Старше предыдущих, но может быть полезна для ознакомления с историей развития языка.

Dart Apprentice: Fundamentals, Jonathan Sande. Kodeco Inc., 2021. ISBN 978-1950325473.

Основы Dart, Станислав Чернышев. Питер, 2024. ISBN 978-5-4461-4168-5.


Видеокурсы и лекции:
*
Основные книги и ресурсы по Flutter:
Учебные онлайн-ресурсы:

Официальная сайт Flutter: https://flutter.dev/ - исчерпывающий ресурс по всем аспектам Flutter.
Flutter API Docs: https://api.flutter.dev/ - всегда самая актуальная документация по Flutter.
Flutter Cookbook: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook -  коллекция рецептов, демонстрирующих решение распространенных задач в Flutter.
Codelabs от Google: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?product=flutter -  интерактивные руководства, которые помогут изучить Flutter на практике.

Другие полезные ресурсы:

Flutter Community: https://flutter.dev/community - ссылки на различные ресурсы сообщества Flutter, включая форумы, чаты и группы в социальных сетях.
Awesome Flutter: https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter - курируемый список статей, библиотек, инструментов и других ресурсов для Flutter.
r/FlutterDev (subreddit): https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/ - сообщество Reddit, где можно задавать вопросы, делиться опытом и обсуждать Flutter.

Книги:

Beginning Flutter with Dart: A practical guide to cross-platform mobile development, Rap Payne. Apress, 2021. ISBN 978-1-4842-6227-5. На русском языке перевода не найдено. Отличный выбор для начинающих, объединяет изучение Dart и Flutter.

Flutter in Action, Eric Windmill. Manning Publications, 2020. ISBN 9781617296361. На русском языке перевода не найдено.  Практическое руководство по разработке Flutter-приложений.

Flutter Apprentice (First Edition),  Matt Galloway, Angela Yu. Ray Wenderlich, 2021. На русском языке перевода не найдено. Хорошо структурированный учебник для начинающих.

Building a Web App with Flutter,  Rap Payne. Apress, 2022. ISBN 978-1-4842-8082-8  На русском языке перевода не найдено.  Книга посвящена  разработке веб-приложений с помощью Flutter.

Основы Flutter, Станислав Чернышев. -, 202?. ISBN -.


Видеокурсы и лекции:

Официальный канал Flutter: https://www.youtube.com/@flutterdev/ - много коротких видео, демонстрирующие возможности Flutter.
LazyLoad Dart & Flutter, Евгений JonFir Елчев: https://www.youtube.com/@LearnDartFlutter
Flutter & Dart от Стаса Ильина: https://www.youtube.com/@frezycode - Он является профессиональным разработчиком на Flutter и до сих пор выпускает всё новые и новые уроки.

